# Invalid ELF Header error while using dlfcn.h library functions

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am trying to create a little library with 3 functions in c. Here is my codes:

mm_alloc.h:

```
/*
 * mm_alloc.h
 *
 * A clone of the interface documented in "man 3 malloc".
 */

#pragma once

#include <stdlib.h>

void *mm_malloc(size_t size);
void *mm_realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
void mm_free(void *ptr);
```

Inside of the three function above is empty for now

mm_test.c

```
#include "assert.h"
#include "dlfcn.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

/* Function pointers to hw3 functions */
void* (*mm_malloc)(size_t);
void* (*mm_realloc)(void*, size_t);
void (*mm_free)(void*);

void load_alloc_functions() {
    void *handle = dlopen(".(Its path here)../mm_alloc.h", RTLD_NOW);
    if (!handle) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        exit(1);
    }

    char* error;
    mm_malloc = dlsym(handle, "mm_malloc");
    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        exit(1);
    }

    mm_realloc = dlsym(handle, "mm_realloc");
    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        exit(1);
    }

    mm_free = dlsym(handle, "mm_free");
    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        exit(1);
    }
}

int main() {
    load_alloc_functions();
}
```

My OS is Ubuntu. Here is how I compile the code:

```
gcc mm_test.c -o tmp -ldl
```

When I run the tmp, it gives "Invalid ELF Header". How can I solve this?

Comment: Off-topic, but `mm_malloc` and friends deal with 16-byte aligned data. Be sure your replacement provides the same alignment qualities. I mention it because some systems don't provide heap memory aligned on 16-byte boundaries (Solaris comes to mind).

Comment: I will keep this in my mind, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dlopen()` can only load shared library files (`.so` files), not C header files.

You will need to implement these functions and compile them into a shared library to load.

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks a lot.